# setting up AOSP repository for local git server

Tags: git, android-source, gerrit, mirror

requirement is that i have to setting up a particular AOSP source code (eg:android-12.1.0_r12) for my local git server which is available on google android page and other people( client machine ) from our organization can able to download ( using repo init < --- > and repo sync from their system .

please share what are the steps needs to follow for this requirement. Please share in details.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the AOSP codebase as mirror:

```
mkdir AOSP_MIRROR
cd AOSP_MIRROR
repo init -u AOSP_URL -b BRANCH --mirror
repo sync
```

2. Setup GIT daemon:

```
git daemon --port=PORT --export-all --reuseaddr --base-path=AOSP_MIRROR
```

Then other people can sync code:

```
repo init -u git://YOUR_GIT_SERVER_IP:PORT/platform/manifest -b BRANCH
repo sync
```

If you want more advanced management, try [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/).